# How to parse the sentence " I never really peaked because my life is still growing because I shoot different paths "

Tags: sentence-construction

The following sentence is from the VOA Leaning English program:

> Lou Ferrigno also is known for playing a superhero. The former bodybuilder was “The Incredible Hulk,” a green-skinned comic
>   book character on the television series of the same name. The show was
>   popular in the late 1970s and early 80s. Lou Ferrigno says he has
>   dealt with the ups and downs of fame by doing different things.
>
> “Well, for me, ***I never really peaked because my life is still
>   growing because I shoot different paths***, like bodybuilding, like
>   the movies, like I became a deputy sheriff. So everything is spread
>   out.”

How to parse this sentence which is in bold? It has got two "because" here？

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty bad sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

> **Lou**:  I never really peaked.
>   **Interviewer**:  Why do you say that?
>   **Lou**:  Because my life is still growing.
>   **Interviewer**:  Why is it still growing?
>   **Lou**:  Because I shoot different paths
>   **Interviewer**:  What kind of paths?
>   **Lou**:  Like, bodybuilding, movies, becoming a sheriff.

Comment: Note that "shoot different paths" makes very little sense: the imagery doesn't really fit together.

Comment: @horatio- Yes, if I were betting on which part of the sentence a non-native speaker would have trouble with, it'd be the "*shoot different paths*" part.  I assume it to mean he has taken different paths in life with a usage of *shoot* similar to *shooting the rapids* in kayaking.

Answer (score 0):

I split up the sentence a bit with the order of the events. Understand the point *k* as the cause of point *k+1*:

> 1. I shoot different paths, like bodybuilding ...
> 2. So my life is still growing.
> 3. So I never really peaked.
> 4. So everything is spread out.

See, usually the sentence following the word *because* is the cause of the sentence preceding it.